# fbjni/fbjni.h file not found react-native

Tags: android, react-native

`fbjni/fbjni.h file not found` error in react-native when building the android version of RN app.

App to build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

try either :

1. rm -rf node_modules && yarn install (worked for me)

or

These steps:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Add android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in
   android/gradle.properties
3. Reopen project and build.